# Adjective for something that increases in difficulty

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm creating a game and in the name I want to include an adjective that shows something that increases in difficulty. The problem is that I don't have that great of a vocabulary and the internet didn't seem to help. I don't even think there is such a word that can explain that. If there is no such word than I would appreciate it if you gave me words that have a similar meaning to what I am asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm creating a game and in the name I want to include an adjective that shows something that increases in difficulty.

That's called *escalating*.

**Escalating (adj):** becoming more intense or serious. - *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/escalating)*

---

**Escalating (adj):** increasing in price, amount, rate, etc - *[Cambridge English dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/escalating)*

**[Escalate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/escalate) (verb):** to become or make something become greater or more serious.

Answer (score 1):

This is what came to mind.

The contest became got harder over time. And so against *mounting* difficulty the two contestants charged ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You could describe the game as having *[progressive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/progressive) difficulty*.

> Gradually advancing in extent; increasing.